# aggregate initializer vs. implicit structure padding

Tags: c

In code like the following, we typically have an implicit pad of 2 bytes at the end of the structure:

```
struct foo {
  int32_t x ;
  int16_t y ;
// <<< 2 bytes for total sizeof(foo) == 8
} ;
```

I was asked today what an aggregate initializer does with the extra two bytes:

```
foo o = { 0, 0 } ;
```

ie: is this going to be equivalent to

```
foo o ;
memset( &o, 0, sizeof(foo) ) ;
```

I had no clue, so I recommended not to depend on that (aggregate initialers are troublesome anyways so that's good general advise IMO).

Does anybody know if the C language spec says anything about what an aggregate initialization does with implicit padding when the platform ABI requires such padding for the specific structure in question?

Comment: weird, just a thought experiment, or does this affect a project? i would assume that it does not pad it, though there's probably some version of `#pragma pack` on your compiler to remove the padding and make it equivalent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the C99 standard, "Representation of types", 6.2.6:

> When a value is stored in an object of
>   structure or union type, including in
>   a member object, the bytes of the
>   object representation that correspond
>   to any padding bytes take unspecified
>   values.

In short, it is not specified by the language; it's up to the C compiler/interface implementor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably certain there's no requirement about initialization of padding. Just for example, it would be entirely legal for an implementation to add padding to *every* struct, and have it store a tag telling what type of structure it is to support run-time type checking. In such a case, most structs would contain padding that was always non-zero.